# i2c stm32 nucleo unable to establish connection

Tags: c, stm32, i2c, nucleo

I am new to the whole stm32 environment. I've always used arduino in the past and I wanted to try something new for this project.

I am having a really hard time setting up an i2c connection between a nucleo board (MASTER) and an arduino(SLAVE).

I have tested the slave using another arduino as a MASTER and it works fine, then I decided it was time to write the code for the nucleo MASTER.

Here is the code I am using, and it seems pretty straigh foward to me, the problem is that I am unable to communicate with the arduino.

`HAL_I2C_IsDeviceReady`
 always returns `HAL_ERROR`, so my code must have some problems.

```
/* USER CODE BEGIN Header */
/**
  ******************************************************************************
  * @file           : main.c
  * @brief          : Main program body
  ******************************************************************************
  * @attention
  *
  * <h2><center>&copy; Copyright (c) 2019 STMicroelectronics.
  * All rights reserved.</center></h2>
  *
  * This software component is licensed by ST under BSD 3-Clause license,
  * the "License"; You may not use this file except in compliance with the
  * License. You may obtain a copy of the License at:
  *                        opensource.org/licenses/BSD-3-Clause
  *
  ******************************************************************************
  */
/* USER CODE END Header */

/* Includes ------------------------------------------------------------------*/
#include "main.h"

/* Private includes ----------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN Includes */

/* USER CODE END Includes */

/* Private typedef -----------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN PTD */

/* USER CODE END PTD */

/* Private define ------------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN PD */

/* USER CODE END PD */

/* Private macro -------------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN PM */

/* USER CODE END PM */

/* Private variables ---------------------------------------------------------*/
I2C_HandleTypeDef hi2c1;

UART_HandleTypeDef hlpuart1;

/* USER CODE BEGIN PV */

/* USER CODE END PV */

/* Private function prototypes -----------------------------------------------*/
void SystemClock_Config(void);
static void MX_GPIO_Init(void);
static void MX_LPUART1_UART_Init(void);
static void MX_I2C1_Init(void);
/* USER CODE BEGIN PFP */

/* USER CODE END PFP */

/* Private user code ---------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN 0 */

/* USER CODE END 0 */

/**
  * @brief  The application entry point.
  * @retval int
  */
int main(void)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 1 */

  /* USER CODE END 1 */


  /* MCU Configuration--------------------------------------------------------*/

  /* Reset of all peripherals, Initializes the Flash interface and the Systick. */
  HAL_Init();

  /* USER CODE BEGIN Init */

  /* USER CODE END Init */

  /* Configure the system clock */
  SystemClock_Config();

  /* USER CODE BEGIN SysInit */

  /* USER CODE END SysInit */

  /* Initialize all configured peripherals */
  MX_GPIO_Init();
  MX_LPUART1_UART_Init();
  MX_I2C1_Init();
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 2 */
  uint8_t buffer[1];
  buffer[0] = 0;
  buffer[1] = 0;
  /* USER CODE END 2 */

  /* Infinite loop */
  /* USER CODE BEGIN WHILE */
  while (1)
  {
    /* USER CODE END WHILE */

    /* USER CODE BEGIN 3 */
      for(uint16_t i = 0; i <256; i ++){
          if(HAL_I2C_IsDeviceReady(&hi2c1, i, 2, 10)== HAL_OK){
              HAL_I2C_Master_Transmit(&hi2c1, i, buffer, sizeof(buffer), 10);
          }
      }
  }
  /* USER CODE END 3 */
}

/**
  * @brief System Clock Configuration
  * @retval None
  */
void SystemClock_Config(void)
{
  RCC_OscInitTypeDef RCC_OscInitStruct = {0};
  RCC_ClkInitTypeDef RCC_ClkInitStruct = {0};
  RCC_PeriphCLKInitTypeDef PeriphClkInit = {0};

  /** Configure the main internal regulator output voltage 
  */
  HAL_PWREx_ControlVoltageScaling(PWR_REGULATOR_VOLTAGE_SCALE1);
  /** Initializes the CPU, AHB and APB busses clocks 
  */
  RCC_OscInitStruct.OscillatorType = RCC_OSCILLATORTYPE_HSI;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.HSIState = RCC_HSI_ON;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.HSIDiv = RCC_HSI_DIV1;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.HSICalibrationValue = RCC_HSICALIBRATION_DEFAULT;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLState = RCC_PLL_NONE;
  if (HAL_RCC_OscConfig(&RCC_OscInitStruct) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /** Initializes the CPU, AHB and APB busses clocks 
  */
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.ClockType = RCC_CLOCKTYPE_HCLK|RCC_CLOCKTYPE_SYSCLK
                              |RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK1;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.SYSCLKSource = RCC_SYSCLKSOURCE_HSI;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.AHBCLKDivider = RCC_SYSCLK_DIV1;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB1CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV1;

  if (HAL_RCC_ClockConfig(&RCC_ClkInitStruct, FLASH_LATENCY_0) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /** Initializes the peripherals clocks 
  */
  PeriphClkInit.PeriphClockSelection = RCC_PERIPHCLK_LPUART1|RCC_PERIPHCLK_I2C1;
  PeriphClkInit.Lpuart1ClockSelection = RCC_LPUART1CLKSOURCE_PCLK1;
  PeriphClkInit.I2c1ClockSelection = RCC_I2C1CLKSOURCE_PCLK1;
  if (HAL_RCCEx_PeriphCLKConfig(&PeriphClkInit) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
}

/**
  * @brief I2C1 Initialization Function
  * @param None
  * @retval None
  */
static void MX_I2C1_Init(void)
{

  /* USER CODE BEGIN I2C1_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE END I2C1_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE BEGIN I2C1_Init 1 */

  /* USER CODE END I2C1_Init 1 */
  hi2c1.Instance = I2C1;
  hi2c1.Init.Timing = 100000;
  hi2c1.Init.OwnAddress1 = 0;
  hi2c1.Init.AddressingMode = I2C_ADDRESSINGMODE_7BIT;
  hi2c1.Init.DualAddressMode = I2C_DUALADDRESS_DISABLE;
  hi2c1.Init.OwnAddress2 = 0;
  hi2c1.Init.OwnAddress2Masks = I2C_OA2_NOMASK;
  hi2c1.Init.GeneralCallMode = I2C_GENERALCALL_DISABLE;
  hi2c1.Init.NoStretchMode = I2C_NOSTRETCH_DISABLE;
  if (HAL_I2C_Init(&hi2c1) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /** Configure Analogue filter 
  */
  if (HAL_I2CEx_ConfigAnalogFilter(&hi2c1, I2C_ANALOGFILTER_ENABLE) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /** Configure Digital filter 
  */
  if (HAL_I2CEx_ConfigDigitalFilter(&hi2c1, 0) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /* USER CODE BEGIN I2C1_Init 2 */

  /* USER CODE END I2C1_Init 2 */

}

/**
  * @brief LPUART1 Initialization Function
  * @param None
  * @retval None
  */
static void MX_LPUART1_UART_Init(void)
{

  /* USER CODE BEGIN LPUART1_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE END LPUART1_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE BEGIN LPUART1_Init 1 */

  /* USER CODE END LPUART1_Init 1 */
  hlpuart1.Instance = LPUART1;
  hlpuart1.Init.BaudRate = 209700;
  hlpuart1.Init.WordLength = UART_WORDLENGTH_7B;
  hlpuart1.Init.StopBits = UART_STOPBITS_1;
  hlpuart1.Init.Parity = UART_PARITY_NONE;
  hlpuart1.Init.Mode = UART_MODE_TX_RX;
  hlpuart1.Init.HwFlowCtl = UART_HWCONTROL_NONE;
  hlpuart1.Init.OneBitSampling = UART_ONE_BIT_SAMPLE_DISABLE;
  hlpuart1.Init.ClockPrescaler = UART_PRESCALER_DIV1;
  hlpuart1.AdvancedInit.AdvFeatureInit = UART_ADVFEATURE_NO_INIT;
  hlpuart1.FifoMode = UART_FIFOMODE_DISABLE;
  if (HAL_UART_Init(&hlpuart1) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  if (HAL_UARTEx_SetTxFifoThreshold(&hlpuart1, UART_TXFIFO_THRESHOLD_1_8) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  if (HAL_UARTEx_SetRxFifoThreshold(&hlpuart1, UART_RXFIFO_THRESHOLD_1_8) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  if (HAL_UARTEx_DisableFifoMode(&hlpuart1) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /* USER CODE BEGIN LPUART1_Init 2 */

  /* USER CODE END LPUART1_Init 2 */

}

/**
  * @brief GPIO Initialization Function
  * @param None
  * @retval None
  */
static void MX_GPIO_Init(void)
{

  /* GPIO Ports Clock Enable */
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOC_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOF_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOA_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOB_CLK_ENABLE();


}

/* USER CODE BEGIN 4 */

/* USER CODE END 4 */

/**
  * @brief  This function is executed in case of error occurrence.
  * @retval None
  */
void Error_Handler(void)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN Error_Handler_Debug */
  /* User can add his own implementation to report the HAL error return state */

  /* USER CODE END Error_Handler_Debug */
}

#ifdef  USE_FULL_ASSERT
/**
  * @brief  Reports the name of the source file and the source line number
  *         where the assert_param error has occurred.
  * @param  file: pointer to the source file name
  * @param  line: assert_param error line source number
  * @retval None
  */
void assert_failed(uint8_t *file, uint32_t line)
{ 
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 6 */
  /* User can add his own implementation to report the file name and line number,
     tex: printf("Wrong parameters value: file %s on line %d\r\n", file, line) */
  /* USER CODE END 6 */
}
#endif /* USE_FULL_ASSERT */

/************************ (C) COPYRIGHT STMicroelectronics *****END OF FILE****/
```

I don't think the wiring is the problem, because it worked between the 2 arduinos. But I will explain how everything is wired.

**SCL** and **SDA** have both a pull up resistor of 8kohm, I am also using a logic analyzer to monitor the communication, but both **SCL** and **SDA** are alway **HIGH**.

Thank you in advance for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I<sup>2</sup>C peripheral clock is not enabled in RCC**

Each peripheral block should be enabled in some `RCC` register, the exact register bit depends on the series. The calls in `MX_GPIO_Init()` take care of the GPIO blocks, but neither I<sup>2</sup>C1 nor the UART is enabled.

**GPIO pins are not initialized**

Each peripheral I/O pin should be set to a mode appropriate for the peripheral. For I<sup>2</sup>C, this would be *alternate function open-drain output*, for the UART *alternate function input* for RX and *alternate function push-pull output* for TX (unless you have some weird multi-master UART setup). The alternate function numbers for each pin are listed in the datasheet, the rest is documented in the reference manual.

Comment: Thanks berendi, I thought cubeMX would inizialize anything you needed! Seems like I was missing ```__HAL_RCC_GPIOB_CLK_ENABLE();```!
Do you mind giving some more examples of how to configure the GPIO pins for i2c? (I think other people who will have the same problem as me would really love that)

Comment: Pin initialization depends on the hardware in and around the MCU, it's not possible to give an example that works on all STM32 devices and pinout configuration. Read the chapter on *General-Purpose I/Os* in the reference manual for your device, it lists the register values for possible configurations, then set the GPIO registers for the I2C pins accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, a "general" c error:

```
uint8_t buffer[1];
buffer[0] = 0;
buffer[1] = 0;
```

`buffer`has only a size of 1, so `buffer[1]`is an illegal memory access.

And the I2C Problem:

It seems you code is missing the pin initialization. You should have a `HAL_I2C_MspInit()` funcktion to do that job.

Normally the CubeMx should create this function with the pins you selected for the peripheral. Maybe you have switche to the LL (LowLevel) Library on the Project-> Advance tab for the I2C->GPIOs

Comment: Thanks theSealion, yep! that was my bad!!